# Dungeon Lords Questions - Really Hard!

Tags: dungeon-lords, puzzles

Dungeon Lords (amazing game!) has a free-to-download "Minions Bearing Gifts" expansion at its website.  However, the expansion is only recommended for expert players of the game, and to give an indication of just *how* expert, the designers have included a quiz that you are advised to score well on before you even think about downloading the expansion.

The quiz is really, really, hard.  Having played maybe half a dozen games of Dungeon Lords, I wasn't expecting to ace it... but I got 1/7.

I thought it might be fun for us to try our hand at working out the answers to the questions together.  After all, there's no reason we can't collaborate in our efforts to become experts at the game!  Without further ado, the quiz:

---

*There are 7 pretty tricky questions. Think well, as there might be a catch. The correct answers might include situations that are theoretically allowed by the rules but probably never happen (as they require improbable yet possible card configurations and player behavior).*

1. If you have to gain more evil than evilometer allows you, you are not gaining any. Can this theoretically happen in the second round of the game?

   a. No.
   b. Yes.
   c. Yes, but only if you hire at least one Vampire.
   d. Yes, but only if you hire two Vampires.
2. What is the theoretical maximum number of imps a player can accumulate during a 4 player game?
3. What is the highest possible damage one trap can deal?
4. Can it happen that an illusionary hero created by Second Year’s Illusion spell survives a combat round?

   a. He usually does.
   b. He never does.
   c. He can survive only a round in which was party not conquering.
   d. Theoretically, it can survive even a round in which was party conquering.
5. What is the theoretical maximum number of actually healed damage in a single round of combat if there is no paladin involved?
6. What is the lowest possible score you can achieve in the game.
7. It is start of the last round of a 2 player game (fall of Second Year) and opponent has no production room. If scored now, you would win all 7 exclusive titles. May it happen you score no title (exclusive nor shared) at the end of the game?

   a. No, you will keep at least one shared title.
   b. Yes, but your opponent has to use all three minion actions well this round.
   c. Yes, even if your opponent does not perform one of his minion actions.
   d. Yes, even if your opponent does not perform two of his minion actions.

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for the answers or just comments.

Comment: @Egg - I'm a long way away from knowing the answer to all 7 questions, so if someone beats me to it (with working shown!) I will accept theirs as the correct answer.  In the meantime though I'd love any comments about ways to tackle some of the harder questions... your comment certainly helped clarify some of my ideas about the fastest ways to gain lots of Evil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked through the seven questions myself when I first bought them game, but as I don't remember the answers right off the top of my head, I'll preface this answer with the statement that I've gotten the following answers off of a thread BoardGameGeek.

**Question 1:** If you have to gain more evil than evilometer allows you, you are not gaining any. Can this theoretically happen in the second round of the game?

On round 1 and 2 you play food, getting on the third space (in round one two people do it before your first placement). Thats 4 evil.

On round 2 title envy event occurs. You collect 1 evil per title, for the following: 
Most evil (from your 4 evil from food)
Most room (1 vs 0/0/0)
Most tunnels (You dug 2, no one else dug, 4/3/3/3 after the room)
Most monsters (1 vs 0/0/0)
Most imps (4 vs 0/0/0)
Most resources (you gained off the food, they spent some if needed).

Note that you cannot collect 'fewest conquered tiles'.

Thats 10 evil, maxing you out, but we still need one more, so your Monster that you recruited is a Witch for one evil. (Vampire not needed. Ghost doesnt count as a monster for monsterlord).

Your three actions each round combine to these 6 actions:
Food, Food, Tunnel, Imps, Monster, Room.

We go above the top of the evilometer on Title Envy when the final title is awarded. (Note: that Witch recruit was before the title payout, so yes it works).

**Question 2:** What is the theoretical maximum number of imps a player can accumulate during a 4 player game?

30
3 from the beginning of the game, 12 from magic room (4 x 1 in first year, 4 x 2 in second year), 15 from actions (the player have to take imps as first action each round except last round, so he will be at least once first and so obtain only one imp 7 x 2 + 1 x 1).

**Question 3:** What is the highest possible damage one trap can deal?

Nine. Poisonous food used onto eight life adventurer with one extra life because of magic food.

**Question 4:** Can it happen that an illusionary hero created by Second Year’s Illusion spell survives a combat round?

Theoretically, it can survive even a round in which was party conquering.
1st round – illusion is created. Party doesn’t conquer.
2nd round – illusion is boosted by magic food. Party doesn’t conquer.
3rd round – illusion survives one fatigue from conquering.

**Question 5** What is the theoretical maximum number of actually healed damage in a single round of combat if there is no paladin involved?

Ten. Party composed from two priests with three hearts each and one wizard (three casting symbols). Initially an illusionary hero with two wounds is created (analogical to previous answer) in first two rounds. Also some damage is dealt among the adventures. In the third round slime hits the party, the wizard casts healing spell and one wound is healed to each member of the party including the illusionary hero. Two priests heal the rest six wounds.

**Question 6** What is the lowest possible score you can achieve in the game?

-72. You can have sixteen tunnels which results in 8 x -3 points each year for unpaid taxes. Nine tunnels were destroyed by adventures 9 x -2 (once double conquering because of the spell) and the visiting minister of Dungeons was hungry (2 x -3).
Summary: -48 (unpaid taxes) -18 (destroyed tunnels) – 6 (visiting minister) = -72

**Question 7** It is start of the last round of a 2 player game (fall of Second Year) and opponent has no production room. If scored now, you would win all 7 exclusive titles. May it happen you score no title (exclusive nor shared) at the end of the game?

Yes, even if your opponent does not perform one of his minion actions.

First player has all titles, second has none.
Second player dig four tunnels as his first action and hire monster as second action. First player’s actions are chosen so that they do not interfere with loosing titles.
Special event is an Earthquake. First player looses two rooms, second player looses two tunnels (Other option is the Extra tax special event).
The Lord of Dark Deeds – lost in the combat (because of destroyed tiles)
The Lord of Halls – lost because of an Earthquake
The Tunnellord – lost by the only minion action of the second player
The Monsterlord – lost in the combat (because of Dimensional gate)
The Lord of Imps – lost in the combat (two or three Kamikadze Ims)
The Lord of Riches – lost in the combat (two or more traps used)
The Battlelord – lost in the combat (because of destroyed tiles)
Second player doesn’t loose any tile or monster in the combat and he uses no traps (For example party of a paladin and three rogues (the case the first player has taken action Improve Reputation so the second player is the most evil from the beginning of the combat), first round a daemon and a dragon in the Anti-magic Room, second round a goblin finishes the three wounded rogues in Training Room).

Comment: I eventually found that thread too, which kind of took the fun out of it for me - but you have correctly answered the question!  What a complicated game :D

Comment: @thesunneversets I had guessed as much, as a 'Dungeon Lord Quiz' google pulls up the answers in the first couple of hits now, but I figured that the answer should find it's way back here just for completion's sake.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Yes you can, and I think "C", but for sure "D".**

I don't have the board in front of me (so I don't remember what the amount you have to lose is to get to the maximum), but I think that it goes something like this:

#### Turn one

- get 2 evil from Food
- buy vampire (2 evil)

#### Turn two

- buy second vampire (2 evil)
- Event "PayDay" makes you pay 4 more evil.

That's ten evil lost in two turns.  You can do it with one vampire if you only need to lose 8 (*substitute the second purchase for another -2 for food*).

Sound right?

Comment: The real question is, can you max out on evil without hiring any vampires?  I'm suspecting that there must be a way...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably going to be an ongoing mission, but I'm going to post my workings here as I go along, and see what we end up with.

**Question 1**: It's clearly possible to gain 10 evil by the end of the second turn by hiring Vampires at 2 Evil a pop, and then paying them off on PayDay.  The question is, can we get to 10 Evil in two turns without the help of Vampires?  I'm currently thinking that the answer is yes, and that this is acheived through the Special Event "Title Envy" (gain 1 Evil for each exclusive title you currently have).  Between this, gaining up to 4 Evil from Food acquisition, and up to 2 Evil from hiring Witches or Ghosts, I can't imagine it would be impossible to make it to 10 Evil without a single Vampire in one's employ.  Right?

**Question 2**: I spent forever wondering why the answer to this wasn't 31.  You start with 3 imps, you buy the Magic Room, you get 2 imps per turn with your actions, 1 new imp per turn in the Magic Room in the first year, 2 new imps per turn in the Magic room in the second year.  3 + 16 + 12 = 31.  But of course (these questions are fiendish!) you can't always get 2 imps with an action.  To use the same action every turn for the entire game you have to use it as your first action every time, or else it becomes an inaccessible action.  If you are always taking Imps as your first action, then it will sometimes coincide with you being first player, and you will only get 1 new imp that turn.  Suppose you are sitting in fourth seat: on the last turn of the second year you don't need Imps to be your first action, but on the last turn of the first year you do.  So you lose 1 imp to the seating order and end the game with a still fairly incredible army of **30 Imps**.

Comment: Never heard of that event.  Maybe we haven't played with it yet....

Comment: @Egg: There's another Special Event that gives you 3 Evil if you have the most monsters.  But I think it's safe to say that Title Envy offers the largest potential for a massive one-shot Evil swing.  I don't know if you could actually achieve 7 Evil from it on Turn 2, trying to work that out makes my brain ache, but I think 4 Evil from it seems like a pretty safe bet.